# How to get child to fill all horizontal space when parent is "overflow: scroll"

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am currently working on a react application and am stuck on a certain styling bug. In my application, I have react components that are almost identical to the ones seen below:

[JS Fiddle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi7Sh.png)

My question is how to get the smaller element (the div with class "wanted-long") to span the entire width of the parent (even the parts you have to scroll right to get to). This is currently not happening as we can see that the blue line in the picture only takes up the width of the visible screen and thus will stop if we scroll to the right a little further.

Thank you so much!

EDIT: Changed image of JSFiddle to more accurately reflect what is going on in my application.

Comment: can you share the link to JS Fiddle?

Comment: I deleted the fiddle I was working on to create that example :(. I can create another one if it helps. I do not have a JSFiddle account so I did not think to do it initially.

Comment: Yes, that will help to test things. You can create a codepen instead if you want.

Comment: The red element is overflowing the container, to make the blue element width the same as the red element, you will need javascript. Or you can set `max-width: 100%:` on the red element and stop it from overflowing

Comment: Hey! I looked back at the JSFiddle I sent and think that it was misleading. Here is the link to the newest one: https://jsfiddle.net/ll3333/5v42sqb1/15/

Comment: But going back to your comment @Khalil, I would like the user to be able to scroll to the right when the red element overflows the parent. I just want the blue element to be the same length as the red one when this happens (user should continue seeing blue element when they scroll)

Comment: Would you consider a JavaScript solution?

Comment: Yes, but I would highly prefer not to. Is this not possible using just CSS? I feel like this sort of thing should happen somewhat frequently in web applications?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will be helpful for you

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
   height:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue; 
}
.long-element {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:red;
    height:30px;
}
/*.wanted-long {*/
/*    width:100%;*/
/*    display:flex;*/
/*    background-color:blue;*/
/*    height:10px;*/
/*}*/
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="long-element"></div>
    <div class="wanted-long"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I think there was a misunderstanding! My problem is that i want the blue line to have the width of the entire parent (it should have the same width as the red element in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this......

```css
.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 100%;
   height:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue; 
  width:100%;
}
.long-element {
    width:1000px;
    background-color:red;
    height:30px;
}
/*.wanted-long {*/
/*    width:100%;*/
/*    display:flex;*/
/*    background-color:blue;*/
/*    height:10px;*/
/*}*/
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="long-element"></div>
    <div class="wanted-long"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Can the styles be applied to the "wanted-long" div? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollWidth` property to get the scrollable width of the element.

```
const setWidth = (element) => {
  let width = element.parentNode.scrollWidth;
  element.style.width = width + 'px';
}

setWidth( document.querySelector('.wanted-long') );
```